# any logs/steps to debug azure stream analytics job available?

Tags: azure, debugging, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Referring to the below link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/04/18/troubleshooting-azure-stream-analytics-jobs-on-new-portal-2/
there is no such thing called "Audit logs" in stream analytics job !

The issue is - My Eventhub has 'outgoing messages' but "No available data" in stream analytics job

I raised support ticket. But minimum it will take 2 days to resolve in that way.

Answer (score 0):

When using the classic portal, go to the Stream Analytics Job , tabpage "Dashboard" and look for the link to "Operation Logs" near the bottom right.

In the new portal, go to the Stream Analytics Job and open the Activity log (second item of the menu, just below "Overview")

Comment: Basically 'Activity log' lists actions performed on the job. such as 'start', 'stop', 'write input', 'update input'. It is not showing any logs so that I can debug whats wrong with my job.

Comment: As I mentioned, My Eventhub has 'outgoing messages' but "No available data" in stream analytics job. My aim is to debug this